# PostgreSQL multi-version install on same server

Tags: linux, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Postgres on LINUX with two verions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278129/how-to-install-postgres-on-linux-with-two-verions)

I've installed multiple `PostgreSQL` version(9.0.3, 8.4.6) on same server . 
I've changed `PORT` also.
I used to run:

```
 psql -h localhost -p 5437 -U postgres8 -d postgres.
```

It is working fine. But showing old version (8.3) instead of 8.4.

what is my mistake? Please help me...

Comment: How many [dups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292358/how-to-run-multiple-postgresql-on-linux-migrated) of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275135/how-to-install-postgres-on-linux-with-two-verions-migrated) are you going to open?

Comment: Stop posting the same question! If you have more detail to put into your question please edit your original post to fine tune it, but please don't keep adding new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean the version output of your `psql` binary. Try to make the server version visible:

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 5437 -U postgres8 -d postgres
SELECT version();
```

To avoid problems, I'd recommend to either use the `psql` binary from PostgreSQL 9 or to use the `psql` binary that matches the server version. Unter Debian/Ubuntu you'll find the binaries under `/usr/lib/postgresql/<VERSION>/bin/psql`.